# If statement not working correctly?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm running wordpress and this is to search.  Basically, I'm going to set the post type based on what checkboxes are selected (if they're checked, they pass a value of 1).

When searching my URL includes `job=1&opportunity=1&resource=1`, and I've tried the values both with and without quotes, it will not output `HELLO` at all.

```
$job = wp_specialchars(stripslashes($_GET["job"]), 1);
$opportunity = wp_specialchars(stripslashes($_GET["opportunity"]), 1);
$resource = wp_specialchars(stripslashes($_GET["resource"]), 1);

if(($job == '1') && ($opportunity == '1') && (resource == '1')){
    echo 'HELLO';
}elseif($job == '1' && $opportunity == '1'){

}elseif($job == '1' && resource == '1'){

}elseif($opportunity == '1' && resource == '1'){

}elseif($job == '1'){

}elseif($opportunity == '1'){

}elseif($resource == '1'){

}
```

Also, if anyone can make this a shorter/more semantic if statement, by all means, go for it.

Comment: Basic debugging first - can you do a test output of the three variables? What does it show?

Comment: You appear to be missing a `$` in front of `resource` in the first, third, and fourth conditionals. PHP would interpret that as `"resource" == "1"`, which is always `false`.

Answer (score 1):

If above code is pasted then look at the following:

```
if(($job == '1') && ($opportunity == '1') && (resource == '1')){

resource should be $resource


}elseif($opportunity == '1' && resource == '1'){

resource should be $resource
```

You might want to try these and execute again (although errors might be expected with the above code).

Comment: I guess I did forget the `$`.  Silly me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a typo:

```
 if(($job == '1') && ($opportunity == '1') && (resource == '1')){
```

`$` is missing for `resource`.

Make sure you have error reporting turned on (`error_reporting(E_ALL);` - this particular issue will throw a `E_NOTICE` level warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(($job == '1') && ($opportunity == '1') && (resource == '1')){
                                              ^--missing a $ here

}elseif($job == '1' && resource == '1'){
                       ^--- and here

}elseif($opportunity == '1' && resource == '1'){
                               ^---and here too
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed it 3 times... Thanks for noticing! I've been looking at code for far too long today.

Comment: turn on display_errors and bump up the warning level. PHP would normally warn you about undefined constants, which'd let you catch this before you had to bang you head on the desk. It's good to keep warnings/errors at max level during development, otherwise you have a helluva time figuring out what's wrong